# Sending push notifications to android by nodejs server

Tags: node.js, android-development, socket.io

I am having the requirement in my project, that nodejs server has to send the notification (kind of push notification) to our mobile, and user( or mobile holder ) have to act on that notification like processing some action, and post back to the nodejs server. As I am very new to the android development, I want to know that, 
1. Is it possible to post notification to any android phone by using device ID kind of unique ID from nodejs ?
2. Is it possible to send response from android to nodejs server, as a response to the push notification? 
3. I came across the term called Google cloud messaging ( or ) firebase cloud messaging. Is it helps to my requirement ?

Comment: push notifications work on an operating system level and not on a per-app or per-website level, so that the device doesn't have to spend lots of power for maintaining a connection with your server. That is why you effectively have to use Google's service for push notifications. Push notifications are unidirectional, but once your app receives a notification it can establish a direct connection with your server.

Comment: is it possible to read the push notification by an android app, and establish the connection with server through that application.

Comment: yes, exactly! For example, a messaging app may receive a push notification that wakes the app. The app could then connect to the server to load any media like images from a server; those would be too big for the push notification.